# Using matplotlib from commandline, not python

Tags: kotlin, matplotlib, command-line

I used matplotlib in Python notebook in the old days, but now I am experimenting with Kotlin... is it possible to generate PNG or SVG plots using matplotlib from command-line in the same way graphviz allows you to with the "dot" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose instead of generating some data file, I could generate a .py file with hardcoded data, run the "python3" command on it, and voila, an SVG pops out. I expected matplotlib to offer something similar to "dot" command but this will also work.